# Handling Long-Running Processes in an ASP.net Web API 2 Service

Tags: c#, asp.net, rest

I created a REST service using ASP.net Web API 2.  The service allows a client to POST records which are stored in a SQL Server database.  At this point *some other process* needs to pull the records from the database, process them, and send the results to another, separate REST service.

Since the processing of the records will be time-consuming, I don't want to perform this step as part of the POST action, but I'm trying to figure out the best approach to designing this *other process*.

Is there a way to integrate this functionality into the ASP.net REST API project, or is something like a Windows Service the best solution?

Comment: Take a look at this post from Scott Hanselman: http://www.hanselman.com/blog/HowToRunBackgroundTasksInASPNET.aspx

Comment: Thanks for that.  Unfortunately I have to rely strictly upon functionality provided by pure .NET, no external libraries.  QueueBackgroundWorkItem is the only viable option, but it looks like it's more for creating a 1-time long-running process.  For our needs we need this process to run continuously around the clock.

Answer (score 0):

You could write your web service asynchronously. So that,

```
public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> PostRecords(Records records)
{
    await [POST data to db]

    // process records asynchronously without awaiting

}
```

You can also perform the post operation synchronously and at the same time track the completion of the post in your database. And as you mentioned, have a job or windows service process the completed posts separately.

Comment: I've changed my POST to be asynchronous.  However, the developers who are performing the POST are requesting that I immediately return a response once I receive the data.  Only after that can I start my 'other process'.   Is there a way to spawn a new thread from the controller which would run on its own so that a response can be relayed to the client immediately after it is received?

Comment: After the post is complete, store some meta data and its status into the database as well and return the posted data immediately. Write up a separate windows service or db job that checks for completed operations and perform your 'other process'.

Comment: I tried that route but was unfortunately told by the architects that everything has to be handled within the Web API project.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Quartz.NET scheduling library within the asp.net mvc or web api. Define a job which executes your query and fire the job from your post action.